# Different voltage differences for a UART signal (when tested from one microcontroller, vs when tested between two microcontrollers)

Tags: pic, uart, ground, msp430, pic24f

I have a question regarding UART signals.

I am doing a project where I press a pushbutton (BTN0, BTN1, BTN2) it registers at a microcontroller ([MSP430FR6989](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR6989?keyMatch=MSP430FR6989&tisearch=Search-EN-everything&usecase=GPN)), transmits a signal to another microcontroller ([PIC24FJ1024GB610](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC24FJ1024GB610)) and it in return toggles one of the LEDs (LED0, LED1, LED2).

both micros have a High logic of 3.3V.

I programmed the MSP430 to transmit a signal via UART, and the PIC24F to receive a UART signal. Tested them separately both were working properly.

I debugged the MSP430 Tx pin with reference to the ground with an oscilloscope, when I press a button I get this signal:

[image]

However when I connected the TX pin of the MSP430 to the RX pin of the PIC24, pressed the button I get this signal:

[image]

---

I thought maybe the problem was the grounds weren't connected together only the MSP430's TX pin was connected to the PIC24's RX pin, like in the figure below:

[image]

However when I connected the grounds together (like in the figure below), the problem didn't go away:

[image]

---

Can someone help me with my issue.

PS I am using [Explorer 16/32](https://www.microchip.com/developmenttools/ProductDetails/DM240001-3) development board for the PIC24 and [MSP-EXP430FR6989](https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=MSP-EXP430FR6989&keyMatch=MSP-EXP430FR6989&tisearch=Search-EN-everything) for the MSP430

**EDIT 1**

This is the code relevant to the PIC24 UART pins FYI

`UART_Setup.h`

```
#ifndef XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H
#define XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H

//code

#define CONFIG_U1TX (RPOR2bits.RP4R = 3)//RP4 -> U1TX -> P69
#define CONFIG_U1RX (RPINR18bits.U1RXR = 3)//RP3 -> U1RX -> P70

//code

void setup_UART_Pins (void);

//code

#endif
```

`UART_Setup.c`

```
#include "xc.h"
#include "UART_SETUP.h"

//code

void setup_UART_Pins (void)
{
    TRISDbits.TRISD10 = 0;
     //just changed TRISD10 from 1 (input) -> 0 (output)

    TRISDbits.TRISD9 = 1;
    //just changed TRISD9 from 0 (output) -> 1 (input)

    CONFIG_U1TX;
    CONFIG_U1RX;

    asm volatile    ("MOV #OSCCON, w1   \n"
                    "MOV #0x46, w2      \n"
                    "MOV #0x57, w3      \n"
                    "MOV.b w2, [w1]     \n"
                    "MOV.b w3, [w1]     \n"
                    "BSET OSCCON, #6");
    //this is for the PPS 
}

 //code
```

in `main.c`

```
#include "xc.h"
#include "UART/UART_SETUP.h"

//code

int main(void) 
{
    //code

    setup_UART_Pins ();

    //code

    while(1);


    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to the advice I got here, I fixed the issue, it turned out I wrongly configured the UART pins of the PIC24, I fixed the code and the issue was gone.

Here is the new relevant code:

`UART_SETUP.h`

```
#ifndef XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H
#define XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H

#define U1RX_INPUT (TRISDbits.TRISD9 = 1)
#define U1RX_CONFIG (RPINR18bits.U1RXR = 4)

#define U1TX_OUTPUT (TRISDbits.TRISD10 = 0)
#define U1TX_CONFIG (RPOR1bits.RP3R = 3)

//code

void setup_UART_Pins (void);

//code

#endif  /* XC_HEADER_TEMPLATE_H */
```

In `UART_SETUP.c`

```
#include "xc.h"
#include "UART_SETUP.h"

//code

void setup_UART_Pins (void)
{    
    U1RX_INPUT;
    U1RX_CONFIG;

    U1TX_OUTPUT;
    U1TX_CONFIG;

    asm volatile    ("MOV #OSCCON, w1   \n"
                    "MOV #0x46, w2      \n"
                    "MOV #0x57, w3      \n"
                    "MOV.b w2, [w1]     \n"
                    "MOV.b w3, [w1]     \n"
                    "BSET OSCCON, #6");
}

//code
```

Comment: How the boards are powered? If from same source, then they share ground already, so that was not the issue to begin with. Most likely the PIC24F RX pin is incorrectly configured as output, please check that it is configured as input - and that there is no other hardware driving it! To which pin you are connecting on the PIC?

Comment: Connecting both grounds is a must - but the second picture looks like the MSP can't pull the line low, so I would check that the RX pin is correctly set up as an input.

Comment: I know this sounds strange, but you're not pulling up that line with a resistor or with the built-in pull-up of either microcontroller, are you?

Comment: @Justme both development boards are powered from the same PC via a USB cable (each uC is connected to a USB port)

Comment: @Forat So they are powered from same PC so they already share ground via USB cable, and thus the ground was not an issue. Please answer the other question, especially, to which PIC pin you are connecting to?

Comment: @Justme I am connected to pin 60 of the PIC242F

Comment: @Justme yes you were right the PIC24 RX pin (RD9) was configured as input (`TRISD9 = 0`) I  changed the `TRISD9 = 1`, however the same issue remains. I also realized that RD9/P69 is a 5.5V tolerant pin, will that create an issue?

Comment: @Arsenal you mean the RX pin of the PIC24? It was set up as an input, I changed it the problem remains

Comment: @MarcusMüller No the UART lines are not pulled up / down using external or internal resistors. The MSP430 inputs are pulled down though

Comment: @Forat For convenience, why not be explicit about it? Is it pin 60 "RA4" on the MCU? Pin 60 "P60_LED7" on the PIM socket on the eval board? Pin 60 of some other connector on the eval board?

Comment: @Justme I apologize, it was P69, P69 on the PIM socket.

Sorry for the mistake

Comment: @Forat Mind also telling us which UART RX pin this is supposed to be, there is like 5 UARTs. U1RX? Also, do you have anything on other connectors (J48, J49, Pictail) that might interfere with P69 ?

Comment: You have configured P69/RP4 to be U1TX output? That won't work. P69 should be RX input pin. From the TX output of the other MCU.

Comment: @Justme the P69 is a PPS pin RP 4 I configured it to U1RX, I am using UART 1. Nothing on the PICtail, on J46 P21, P22, P23 are configured as output (RB4, RB3, RB2) and connected to LEDs on the breadboard, J48 the GND is connected to the breadboard's negative rail, and P69 is the U1RX pin

Comment: Your code says you configure P69 to be U1TX and P70 to be U1RX. Maybe that was the intention, but maybe you have connected MCU TX outputs together, instead of MSP TX output to PIC RX input?

Comment: @Justme you are right I was mixed between in the UART pin configurations, and when I fixed it (will post the fixed code here) the issue was gone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, you have connected MSP TX output pin to PIC pin 69 (RP4), and expecting it to be U1RX input pin.

However, based on your code, you have configured PIC pin 69 (RP4) as U1TX output pin, and pin 70 (RP3) as U1RX input pin.

So the two TX outputs are connected together, and the scope measurement proves it.

Two CMOS outputs driving a same node results in intermediate voltages of about half the supply voltage, and the output being exactly half is explained by output drivers not being equal in strength or external series resistances. PIC board output high driver is stronger than MSP board output low driver, so the MSP board output can only pull the voltage down to 1.9V.

Just change the wiring to connect MSP TX output pin to the actual PIC RX input pin, P70 (RP3), and MSP RX input pin to PIC TX output pin P69 (RP4).

Comment: Yes that was the issue, I went back and configured the UART pins correctly according to the datasheet, and the issue was gone. Thank you for your help.